# MySQL: splitting multiple values in one field, into separate records

Tags: mysql

I have a three-field table like this

```
cat    1    foo|bar|baz
dog    4    foo|quux
horse  6    baz
```

and I want to separate out the values of the third field, demarcated by the | character, to give a new table:

```
cat    1    foo
cat    1    bar
cat    1    baz
dog    4    foo
dog    4    quux
horse  6    baz
```

I could export the table, run some Perl on it, and import it again; but I'd prefer to be able to do it all in SQL.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does not include any SPLIT function but there are plenty of work arounds with replace and substring functions

Comment: Here is a way to implement your own mysql splitting function http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/